# Product page tabs section not showing as tabs

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

Looking at a [stock Luma theme example](http://demo-m2.bird.eu/radiant-tee.html), the details, more information and reviews section is tabbed

[image: stock Luma product page tabs]

However on my site with Luma enabled, these items are not tabbed. Is there some setting to make them behave as tabs?

[image: custom site with luma theme, no tabs]

Comment: looks like there is a product-full-width layout being used on the product page, coming from the page builder module, instead of the traditional catalog_product_view layout. Seems like something new....

Comment: I found [some documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/how-to/how-to-use-full-width-layouts.html#product-full-width) which suggests the tabs should still be present under this "product full width layout", however that does not seem to be the case on my site.

Comment: Please check the console I think there will be a js issue - If yes please share that error might that help to resolve your issue

Comment: Any error on the console log??

Comment: I think the problem is really related with Page Builder. Was you able to fix it (show tabs)?

Answer (score 2):

If have working with magneto 2.4.3 then go to the product edit page via admin panel and expand product design tab  then select layout option no layout update and  select Display Product Options In product info column

Product>>select specific product>>design>>layout>>no layout update

Product>>select specific product>>design>>Display Product Options In >>product info column

after that clear page layout cache and save product and finally refresh specific product view page

Answer (score 1):

> Overrite **details.phtml** and add below code.

**Magento root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view**

> **Without Tab**

**details.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details $block */
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) :?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <!-- <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'> -->
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) :?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <div class="data item title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>">
                        <h3><?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?></h3>
                        <hr/>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content"
                     aria-labelledby="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> **With Tab**

**details.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details $block */
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) :?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) :?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="trigger"
                       href="#<?= $block->escapeUrl($alias) ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content"
                     aria-labelledby="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this has made no difference.

Comment: please disable your all third party module and check it.

Comment: <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'> this line makes tab into page.

Comment: This is right code for magento 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to change layout update in Design tab to No Layout Update for the product.